# javascript innerHTML issue

Tags: javascript

using `obj.innerHTML = "abcxyz <abcxyz@ttt.com>"` getting ouput: abcxyz the rest part is getting ignored because of angle bracket(<>).
so how to achieve the same.

thanks in advace

Comment: The brackets are missing. Try backticks: `\``

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the content is still there, but the browser interprets it as unknown tag, that is, it does not display anything. Look at the generated page source (in FF, e.g., mark all text and use "Selection source" from the context menu).

Try quoting the brackets:

```
obj.innerHTML = "abcxyz <abcxyz@ttt.com>".replace (/</g, "&lt;")
```

This, however, will replace *all* `<`. If you want to embed other HTML, too, you will have to keep track on what you already encoded and what not.

Cheers,

Comment: since i have to replace both the brackets(<>) so we cannt use some regular expression to replace the both

Comment: Try: obj.innerHTML = "abcxyz <abcxyz@ttt.com>".replace (/</g, "&lt;").replace (/>/g, "&gt;")

Comment: Actually you don't really *need* to replace the `>` as well, the HTML parser is savvy enough to keep it allone, if it is not preceeded by an `<`.

Answer (score 2):

HTML encode your string or use HTML entities such as `&lt;`

Comment: ... and there is also a builtin javascript function for that.

Comment: ... that is named how? escape() does URL encoding, if you had that in mind.

Comment: I agree, don't think there's a built in function.  There is a method in prototype.js: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/escapeHTML

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, a literal "<" is represented as "&lt;" and a literal ">" is represented as "&gt;". See [HTML 4.01 section 5.3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.3.2).

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:
unescape('abcxyz %3Cabc...

Comment: How could that be of use? in you unescape it, you again have the `<` in your innerHTML string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape < and > in string.